# How can I apply loops to shave off lines from this convoluted interest rate calculator?

Tags: python, loops, calculator

1. How do I shave off lines from this code? I feel I could use loops to simplify this process.
2. I just started learning python to make my math studies more interesting. I barely know anything about coding so an example would be of great help.
3. The code must include an option to put down an initial capital.
4. Thank you!

   ```
   capital = float(input("Enter initial capital: "))
   interest_rate = float(input("Enter interest rate: "))
   annual_saving = float(input("Enter annual savings: "))
   year = float(input("Enter number of years of saving: "))

   # Y stands for Year
   Y0 = capital + annual_saving
   Y1 = Y0 * (1 + interest_rate)
   Y2 = (Y1 + annual_saving) * (1 + interest_rate)
   Y3 = (Y2 + annual_saving) * (1 + interest_rate)
   Y4 = (Y3 + annual_saving) * (1 + interest_rate)
   Y5 = (Y4 + annual_saving) * (1 + interest_rate)
   Y6 = (Y5 + annual_saving) * (1 + interest_rate)
   Y7 = (Y6 + annual_saving) * (1 + interest_rate)
   Y8 = (Y7 + annual_saving) * (1 + interest_rate)
   Y9 = (Y8 + annual_saving) * (1 + interest_rate)
   Y10 = (Y9 + annual_saving) * (1 + interest_rate)
   Y11 = (Y10 + annual_saving) * (1 + interest_rate)

   if year == 1:
       print(Y1)
   if year == 2:
       print(Y2)
   if year == 3:
       print(Y3)
   if year == 4:
       print(Y4)
   if year == 5:
       print(Y5)
   if year == 6:
       print(Y6)
   if year == 7:
       print(Y7)
   if year == 8:
       print(Y8)
   if year == 9:
       print(Y9)
   if year == 10:
       print(Y10)
   ```

Comment: Suggestions : use array or list instead of 10 variables, use loop for repeated tasks

Comment: You need to learn how to write functions before worrying about loops.  https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, and good luck in your studies! However, Stack Overflow is not the correct place to ask for examples about the basics; it's a Q&A for specific problems. You are correct that loops would simplify your code example, so at your stage, you would be better off learning about those (and other basics) from a textbook or a site. Again, good luck!

Comment: I see. I didn't know where to go. Thank you, Konchog and Itamar Mushkin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for accrued interrest is `K_interrest = K_start * (1 + (p/100))**n` with `p` as your interrest rate and `n` as years. With that we can put your code in a handy function. Your initial fund and annual saving multiplied by interest rate get your new capital. This happens `n` times.

```py
def calculate_savings(k, p, a, n):
    for i in range(n):
        k = (k+a) * (1 + (p/100))
    print(f"{k:.2f}", "$")  # will print your result with 2 decimal digits


capital = float(input("Enter initial capital: "))
interest_rate = float(input("Enter interest rate [%]: "))  # input in percent
annual_saving = float(input("Enter annual savings: "))
years_duration = int(input("Enter number of years of saving: "))  # years must be int here

calculate_savings(capital, interest_rate, annual_saving, years_duration)
```

The other possibility is using a recursive function (a function that calls itself):

```py
def calculate_savings(k, p, a, n):
    if n <= 0:
        print(f"{k:.2f}", "$")
    else:
        k = (k+a) * (1 + (p/100))
        calculate_savings(k, p, a, n-1)  # calculates k with one year less
```

It is generally considered good practice to keep your code DRY (Don't repeat yourself). Also, when your script get's a little more substantial, you should consider catching faulty inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function that will make all calculations and return proper result. Function get 4 variables from input.

```
def calculations(capital, interest_rate, annual_saving, year):
    x = (capital + annual_saving) * (1 + interest_rate)
    for i in range(1, year, 1):
        x = (x + annual_saving) * (1 + interest_rate)
    return x

capital = float(input("Enter initial capital: "))
interest_rate = float(input("Enter interest rate: "))
annual_saving = float(input("Enter annual savings: "))
year = float(input("Enter number of years of saving: "))

results = calculations(capital, interest_rate, annual_saving, year)
print(results)
```